# How do I know why my edit was rolled back?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rollbacks

I recently answered [a question on kendo bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090394/how-to-call-a-parent-method-from-kendo-template-binding/24132342#24132342). In the process, I realized that there was a syntax error that was the root cause of the question. After fixing the syntax error, I caught another semantic error that was not essential to the question (there is a sort that compares the objects when it means to compare properties on the object).

I decided I should edit the question to have only the syntax error. It seems like a good edit that clarifies the question, so I don't understand why it was rolled back.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24090394/revisions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not make any edits to code in questions beyond cleaning up the formatting - and even then you should be very wary of doing that.

The reason your edit was rolled back was probably because it appeared to fix the problem in the code thus making the question redundant.

It would have been better just to address both issues in the answer.